# Invoke-WebRequest, hashtable, Cannot index into a null array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx), but I am getting an error.

I assume that the hash table is causing issues. How can I fix this error?

```psh
$loginBase = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com";
$loginUrl = "$($loginBase)/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa";

# Load the login-page
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $loginUrl -SessionVariable ws;

# Use the session variable that you created in Example 1. Output displays
# values for Headers, Cookies, Credentials, etc. 
$ws;

# Gets the first form in the Forms property of the HTTP response object in the
# $r variable, and saves it in the $form variable. 
$form = $r.Forms[0];

# Displays the keys and values in the hash table (dictionary) object in the
# Fields property of the form.
$form.fields

# The next two commands populate the values of the "email" and "pass" keys of
# the hash table in the Fields property of the form. Of course, you can replace
# the email and password with values that you want to use.
#$form.Fields["email"] = "User01@Fabrikam.com"
#$form.Fields["pass"] = "P@ssw0rd"

# I changed like this, following above example.
# Set the login data 
$form.Fields["Apple ID"] = "1234@yahoo.com";
$form.Fields["Password"]  = "myP2ssword";

# Log in
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginBase + $form.Action) -WebSession $ws -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields

$r.StatusDescription
```

I am getting this error.

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:26 char:1
+ $form.Fields["Apple ID"] = "1234@yahoo.com";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:27 char:1
+ $form.Fields["Password"]  = "myP2ssword";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Method' to the target. Exception
setting "Method": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:30 char:79
+ $r=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginBase + $form.Action) -WebSession $ws -Method $f ...
+                                                                               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Invoke-WebRequest : {"data":null,"messages":{"warn":null,"info":null,"error":["Unauthorized access"]},"statusCode":"ERROR"}
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:35 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest $jsonSummaryUrl -WebSession $ws;
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:36 char:27
+ $json = $response.Content|ConvertFrom-Json
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

**So I edited like this:**

```
$loginBase = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com";
$loginUrl = $loginBase + "/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa";

# Load the login-page
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $loginUrl -SessionVariable ws;

# Use the session variable that you created in Example 1. Output displays
# values for Headers, Cookies, Credentials, etc. 
$ws;

# Gets the first form in the Forms property of the HTTP response object in the
# $r variable, and saves it in the $form variable. 
$form = $r.Forms[0];

# Displays the keys and values in the hash table (dictionary) object in the
# Fields property of the form.
$form.fields

# The next two commands populate the values of the "email" and "pass" keys of
# the hash table in the Fields property of the form. Of course, you can replace
# the email and password with values that you want to use.
#$form.Fields["email"] = "User01@Fabrikam.com"
#$form.Fields["pass"] = "P@ssw0rd"

# I changed like this, following above example.
# Set the login data 
$form.Fields["Apple ID"] = "myusername";
$form.Fields["Password"]  = "mypassword";

# Log in
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginBase + $form.Action) -WebSession $ws -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields

$r.StatusDescription
```

The error is still same.

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:27 char:1
+ $form.Fields["Apple ID"] = "myusername";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:28 char:1
+ $form.Fields["Password"]  = "mypassword";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Method' to the target. Exception
setting "Method": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:31 char:81
+ ... on $ws -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

**This is re-re edited.
Thank you so much for the help.**

```
$loginBase = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com";
$loginUrl = $loginBase + "/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo";

# Load the login-page
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $loginUrl -SessionVariable ws;

# Use the session variable that you created in Example 1. Output displays
# values for Headers, Cookies, Credentials, etc. 
$ws;

# Gets the first form in the Forms property of the HTTP response object in the
# $r variable, and saves it in the $form variable. 
$form = $r.Forms[0];

# Displays the keys and values in the hash table (dictionary) object in the
# Fields property of the form.
$form.fields

# The next two commands populate the values of the "email" and "pass" keys of
# the hash table in the Fields property of the form. Of course, you can replace
# the email and password with values that you want to use.
#$form.Fields["email"] = "User01@Fabrikam.com"
#$form.Fields["pass"] = "P@ssw0rd"

# I changed like this, following above example.
# Set the login data 
$form.Fields["Apple ID"] = "myusername";
$form.Fields["Password"]  = "mypassword";

# Log in
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginBase + $form.Action) -WebSession $ws -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields

$r.StatusDescription

# above this is totally working, under this I am having issue

$jsonSummaryUrl = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/manageyourapps/summary";

$response = Invoke-WebRequest $jsonSummaryUrl -WebSession $ws;
$json = $response.Content|ConvertFrom-Json

# Show me what apps I have

$json.data.summaries
```

the error is

Invoke-WebRequest : {"data":null,"messages":{"warn":null,"error":["Unauthorized access"],"info":null},"statusCode":"ERROR"}
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:36 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest $jsonSummaryUrl -WebSession $ws;
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzurePowerShellISE\Itune.ps1:37 char:27
+ $json = $response.Content|ConvertFrom-Json
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: The errors you posted don't match the code you posted.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, sorry, I edited, if you know the solution, please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Kazu, the error tells us `$form.Fields["Apple ID"] = "myusername";` fails, as if value of `$form` was `$null`. This would happen if the web request to `$loginUrl` fails.  What is `$r.StatusCode` equal to? You want it to be 200.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Thank you for trhe reponse, my password and  username is definitely right, so I am confused about how I can fix this problem.  where and How should I change to make it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $loginUrl variable is off, try the following:

```
$loginBase = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com";
$loginUrl = $loginBase + "/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo";
```

Source: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

Update: You're missing the /wo at the end of the loginUrl try:

```
$loginBase = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com";
$loginUrl = $loginBase + "/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo";

# Load the login-page
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $loginUrl -SessionVariable ws;

# Use the session variable that you created in Example 1. Output displays
# values for Headers, Cookies, Credentials, etc. 
$ws;

# Gets the first form in the Forms property of the HTTP response object in the
# $r variable, and saves it in the $form variable. 
$form = $r.Forms[0];

# Displays the keys and values in the hash table (dictionary) object in the
# Fields property of the form.
$form.fields

# The next two commands populate the values of the "email" and "pass" keys of
# the hash table in the Fields property of the form. Of course, you can replace
# the email and password with values that you want to use.
#$form.Fields["email"] = "User01@Fabrikam.com"
#$form.Fields["pass"] = "P@ssw0rd"

# I changed like this, following above example.
# Set the login data 
$form.Fields["Apple ID"] = "myusername";
$form.Fields["Password"]  = "mypassword";

# Log in
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($loginBase + $form.Action) -WebSession $ws -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields

$r.StatusDescription
```

Comment: Thank you so much for response, I am having still same error, do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: You're still missing the /wo at the end of your loginUrl

Comment: Yes, It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: For your second issue, check the iTunes Connect API's. Also check your web session variable and make sure that some form of authentication is stored within it.

Comment: I found out the way it was missing /wo again. I did like this Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/ra/apps/manageyourapps/summary" -WebSession $ws -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields. BTW, how did you find out this /Wo? I am just very curious.

Comment: I did a quick search of for iTunes Connect API's online and found the github reference, that I included in my first post.